# selenium test automation , IE11 can't access Rich text element using

Tags: selenium, testng, internet-explorer-11

I want to access Rich text editor inside iFrame. There are four iFrames in the page and I want to access by frame element. The code is like below -

```
public static WebElement findRichTextEditorByIframeIndex(WebElement element) {
        getDriver().switchTo().frame(element);
        return getDriver().findElement(By.tagName("body"));
}
```

Process to get iFrame element like below -

```
protected List<WebElement> getIFrameElement() {
        return findElementsByLocatorTag(LocatorTag.IFRAME, "iframe");
    }
```

It works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Edge. But IE11 can't fine the frame element. Also, It can't fine the body inside the iFrame.

```
public static void enterTextInRichTextEditor(WebElement element, String text) {
        try {
            JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
                        jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML ='" + text + "'", element);
            waitForLoad(1);
                switchToDefaultContent();

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Let me know how could I access the element.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What is `element` as in `public static WebElement findRichTextEditorByIframeIndex(WebElement element)`?

Comment: @DebanjanB It's the `IFRAME` element found using `getIFrameElement()`.

Comment: @Rashed But `protected List<WebElement> getIFrameElement()` returns a _List_, how can you pass it as `findRichTextEditorByIframeIndex(WebElement element)`?

Comment: You mention that there are 4 `IFRAME`s on the page but you are locating them using a very generic locator, by tagname = "iframe". Is it possible that in IE the IFRAMEs are different... maybe a different order, etc. When you say that IE can't find it, what error are you getting? I'm guessing it's finding it... it's just not finding the one you want.

Comment: @DebanjanB He's likely passing `getIFrameElement().get(1)` (or whatever the index of the intended `IFRAME` element is) into `findRichTextEditorByIframeIndex()`

Comment: Hi **JeffC**, 
Your assumption might be true. May be I am not getting right order. Basically, that iFrame is the first iFrame in the page. So, I pass getIFrameElement().get(0). 
How Could I find first iFrame in IE11.